# Dismissing View Controller Doesn't Work While Using Navigation Controller

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, dismiss, navigationcontroller

I have two view controllers.

The first one is embedded in a [Navigation Controller](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationcontroller).
On the first view controller there is [Bar Button Item](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibarbuttonitem) which is connected by a segue to the second view controller. The segue is set as Push. Once I go to the second view controller there is a [Bar Button Item](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibarbuttonitem) which is an [IBAction](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibutton?changes=_4) and should dismiss the page, but it doesn't.

Second View Controller Code:

```
import UIKit

class Page2ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    @IBAction func donePressed(_ sender: Any) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

Comment: The opposite of "push" is "pop", not "dismiss".

Comment: @rmaddy what is the function for "pop"

Comment: Look at the documentation for `UINavigationController`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Within your `donePressed(_:)` function, access the navigation controller and call the `popViewController(_:)` function.

```
@IBAction func donePressed(_ sender: Any) {
     navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
}
```